# Publish a previous minor version

Tags: versioning

Many uploads where accomplished without any concern on publishing the major versions.
For example, 0.1 to 0.10 where checked in and 0.3 and 0.8 need to become majors.
Is it possible to go back in the history and publish those as major?
Then, what would happend with the numbering?
What if I publish 0.8 first, then 0.3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't change previous minor versions into being major version but what you can do is following:

1. Check out version 0.10 (it then becomes 0.11)
2. In version history select "Restore" in the menu for 0.3 (it then becomes 0.11)
3. Check-in/Publish as 1.0
4. Check out (it then becomes 1.1)
5. In versions history select "Restore" in the menu for 0.4 (it then becomes 1.1)
6. Check-in as a minor verision
7. Check out (it then becomes 1.2)
8. Iv versions history select "Restore" in the menu for 0.5 (it then becomes 1.2)
9. Check-in as a minor verision
   ...
   xx. In version history select "Delete" in the menu for 0.3
   ...